# Transpose a 2D array - Cannot set property '0' of undefined

Tags: arrays, typescript, transpose

I have a code in typescript to transpose a M x N matrix:

```
private transpose(a: number[][]): number[][] {
    let m: number = a.length;
    let n: number = a[0].length;
    let b: number[][] = [[]]; // Tried without "[[]]"
    for (let i: number = 0; i < m; i++) {
        for (let j: number = 0; j < n; j++) {
            b[j][i] = a[i][j]; // Error
        }
    }
    return b;
}
```

However, I have an error:

`Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined`

How to properly initialize the 2D array?

P.S. Already tried `for..in` but still has problems

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be:

```
let b: number[][] = [];
for (let i: number = 0; i < m; i++) {
    b[i] = [];

    for (let j: number = 0; j < n; j++) {
        b[i][j] = a[j][i];
    }
}
```

You first create an array, and then for each iteration of `i` you create another inner array

Comment: Hi @Nitzan, already added `b[i] = [];` Had to also modify the assignment to `b[i][j] = a[j][i]`, for `b[j]` would not be initialized for the remaining iterations in the inner loop.

Thanks!
Got it working.